# Ошибка поиска модуля (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке импорта as**y**nkundelik выдает исключение, что не может найти as**u**nkundelik. В чём может быть проблема, подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по странице этого модуля на гитхабе, путь к модулю asynkundelik выглядит как KunAPIPy/kunapipy/asynkundelik, возможно стоит написать `from KunAPIPy.kunapipy.asynkundelik import kundelik`.

Comment: Не работает, проблема заключается не в этом, как и описано выше - ищется не asyn-, а asunkundelik. Может быть есть предположения, в чем заключается ошибка.

Comment: @Fugasss Может стоит попробовать импортировать весь модуль целиком?